# Swift DispatchSemaphore is freezing the application

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I tried to run the API service in loops using DispatchSemaphore it's freezing the application,
My requirement is I have call the API to get list of details each details I have different request using that I need to call the API in loops, each API is dependent on the previous API's response hence I used DispatchSemaphore wait and signal method but it's freeing the application

Sample Code:

```
func DownloadInformation(urlString: String, device: String, indexValue: Int, completion: @escaping (_ requestIndex: Int?) -> (Void)) {
        ApiService.sharedInstance.DownloadHealthInsightDetails(ID: self.equipmentAnalaysisArr[indexValue].id) { [self] (serverResponse, error, cardID) -> (Void) in
            if(serverResponse != nil && error == nil) {
                let insightCycleList = serverResponse as? NSDictionary
                if (insightCycleList?["error"]) == nil {
                                                            
                    if let cycle = insightCycleList?["cycles"] as? [AnyObject], cycle.count != 0 {
                        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
                        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
                        let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
                            for i in 0..<cycle.count {
                                if i < 5 {
                                    dispatchGroup.enter()
                                    let element = cycle[i]
                                                                            
                                        self.DownloadCycleData(urlString: blob_url , cycleDownloadCompletion: {_ in
                                            completion(indexValue)
                                            dispatchSemaphore.signal()
                                            dispatchGroup.leave()
                                        })
                                    dispatchSemaphore.wait()
                                }
                            }
                            
                        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                                print("done")
                            }
//                        }
                    } else {
                        self.ShowMessage(index: indexValue, message: self.message)
                    }
                }else {
                    self.ShowMessage(index: indexValue, message: self.message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please give me suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: As a courtesy to potential answerers, please post your *real* code (it is `Void` and not `void`) and *indent* the code properly.

Comment: posted my original code please check it

Comment: Blocking execution is the sole job of a semaphore, this isn't surprising. What is a bit surprising is that you're using a semaphore to serialize all the calls to `DownloadCycleData`. Why are you doing that? IO-related tasks benefit greatly from being able to run concurrently.

Comment: every response depends on the previous one hence I am using semaphore

Comment: or can we achieve this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use your DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue").
But maybe you should consider to use some state machine for such case.

```
if let cycle = insightCycleList?["cycles"] as? [AnyObject], cycle.count != 0 {
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    dispatchQueue.async {
        for i in 0..<cycle.count {
            if i < 5 {
                let cycleSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
                let element = cycle[i]
                self.DownloadCycleData(urlString: blob_url , cycleDownloadCompletion: {_ in
                    completion(indexValue)
                    cycleSemaphore.signal()
                })
                cycleSemaphore.wait()
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will add semaphore signals like you mentioned and see

Comment: but the problem is already we are running the background task (ApiService.sharedInstance.DownloadHealthInsightDetails) will this works again if we doing this inside dispatchQueue?

Comment: then you just don't need **dispatchQueue**

Comment: this is not working cycleSemaphore.wait() block the whole process

Comment: the above code you mentioned are you using two different semaphore?

Comment: yes, two of them